# Rest api to get all Documents from all subsites

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, spfx-webparts

I have 5 subsites (Sub1,Sub2,Sub3,Sub4,Sub5) and all subsites is having Document library name (PublishedDocuments)

```
Sub1 - PublishedDocuments
Sub2 - PublishedDocuments
Sub3 - PublishedDocuments
Sub4 - PublishedDocuments
Sub5 - PublishedDocuments
```

how to fetch  documents from PublishedDocuments library from all Subsite using rest-api , i have to create UI to show all documents in SPFX ,unable to write api to get all subsites and inside library

```
https://<siteurl>/<subsite>/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('PublishedDocuments')/items
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such rest api to get all items from all subsites. You have to loop through the 5 subsites in SPFX, then get all items in each subsite.

Comment: Thanks , i am able to loop in my code and get items .